# How do I get animated series into my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, gif, animated

I was trying to put a GIF into my iphone app, but it just showed the first frame. I read that you have to put this coding into my app with a UIimageView.

```
UIImage *blur5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Picture 12.jpg"];
UIImage *blur6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Picture 13.jpg"];

self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:blur5, blur6, nil];
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
[self.imageView startAnimating];
```

But exactly where and how do I do it? Every time I try to run it, it gives me errors and Xcode freezes.

Comment: what errors are you getting, how are you initialzigin the image view?

Comment: Also, you mention gif but the two images you have specified in your code are jpg.

Comment: As noted, please post what the actual errors are. Also, you are leaking your array. You need to autorelease it since you're assign it to a retaining property.